# Spring Data JPA - Class-based projections with Specification and Pageable

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to identify the best approach for the following scenario. I have few entities in my project where I am applying some concepts of Spring Data JPA in order to have a great service to load entities with DTOs and it is not so difficult to provide maintenance when needed.

```
@Entity
class Order {
  Long id;
  Datetime createdDate;
  String note;
  List<Item> items;
...
}
@Entity
class Item {
  Long id;
  Order order;
  ...
}
```

Currently, I have a service method based on the specification and pageable classes to load my objects.

```
public Page findAll(Specification spec , Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.findAll(spec,pageable);
}
```

This approach is working fine, however, it has some performance issues. I would like to use class-based projections with the specification and pageable classes. Do you guys have a recommendation or an example using this approach?

Regards,

Caique Ferreira

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not yet supported, [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1033) is a bug tracker for it.